# Display categories which only contain entries

Tags: categories

I'm grabbing a list of categories and displaying their entry count.
How can I only display categories which have entires? So I'm not getting any with 0 in them, which is occurring as I have a few entries not yet published with new categories.

```
{% nav category in craft.categories.group('insights') %}
{# Get the count of entries related to `category` #}
{% set entryCount = craft.entries.relatedTo(category).total() %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }} ({{ entryCount }})</a>
    </li>
{% endnav %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple but effective solution would be to just wrap the output in a conditional.

```
{% if entryCount %}
    <li>...</li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Oh that is super simple. Excellent, thanks!